# Whats best way to trace down SqLite open cursor leak?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Somewhere in large android code block is open cursor leak. Over 800 cursors open. Does anyone know best way to pinpoint this? Any way to query to find out how may cursors there are?  Or any way to see where it is happening via profile tools? How would one do this? Large code block don't want to change a lot of code to fix this.  I don't see any place to check number of open cursors on SQLiteDatabase class.

Answer (score 8):

Try this in your onCreate Method

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                 .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .penaltyDeath()
                 .build());
```

The app will crash with a stacktrace when there is a cursor leak :-)

> StrictMode is a developer tool which detects things you might be doing
>   by accident and brings them to your attention so you can fix them

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html

Comment: Interesting. At what point would it notice this? It does crash at 800 open cursors now.  Also what will stack trace tell about location of the leak?

Comment: It would crash the first time you open a cursor and not close it. So build your app and muck about with it a bit and if there  is any leak it will crash. Or if you have tests that cover the bits of code that deal with DB that should do the trick too.

Comment: I still have yet to test it. But I will get it very soon, and let you know.  hope the stacktrace will pinpoint actual location. That's my only doubt.